# how to compress a json list and upload to s3 using java

Tags: java, arrays, json, gzip

I have a JsonNode array that i am trying to compress and upload to s3. below is my code and it is giving me  below error

om.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ObjectOutputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

in the below code , payload is JsonNode[]

```
            GzipCompressorOutputStream gzip = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(obj);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(gzip);
            for(JsonNode record:payload) {
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(record);
            }
         //   gzip.flush();
        //    gzip.close();
            objectOutputStream.close();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            //objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
            byte[] bytesToWrite = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(objectOutputStream);
            ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
            //omd.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
            omd.setContentLength(bytesToWrite.length);
            //   transferManager.upload(bucketName, keyName, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesToWrite), omd);
            s3.putObject(bucketName, keyName,  new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesToWrite), omd);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        byte[] bytesToWrite = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(payload);
        ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GzipCompressorOutputStream gzip = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(obj);
        gzip.write(bytesToWrite);
        gzip.flush(); 
        gzip.close();
        ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
        omd.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
        omd.setContentLength(obj.toByteArray().length);
       
        s3.putObject(bucketName, keyName,  new ByteArrayInputStream(obj.toByteArray()), omd);
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).